# What Java "Dictionary" Type Prints with {}?

Tags: java

What Java type would print to the console this way?

`{'T'=0, 'G'=0, 'A'=0, 'C'=0}`

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a `Map` to me.

Comment: What kind of question is that ?

Comment: You try using 

    `Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`

Where Character is key and Integer is Value.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Still it won't print `'T'=0` it will print `T=0` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer to your question, a simple HashMap will do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('T', 0);
    map.put('G', 0);
    map.put('A', 0);
    map.put('C', 0);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

So for these examples, the map would store the 'C', 'T', 'A', and 'G' values (Character) with the keys 0, 0, 0, and 0 (Integer)

Comment: Thanks! I don't like Java :0

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [`LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) (assuming the order and single quotes are significant). For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("'T'", 0);
    map.put("'G'", 0);
    map.put("'A'", 0);
    map.put("'C'", 0);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Outputs

```
{'T'=0, 'G'=0, 'A'=0, 'C'=0}
```

Comment: Actually, Wrapping a Character into a String is the wrong approach. ;(